# How to get statistic data for specific tags which belong to a specific team?

Tags: support, api, tags

I just want to get statistic data for specific tags which belong to a specific team.
For example, for tags: "abc", I want to know how many users viewed the questions which have the "abc" tag.

Is there an existing Stack Overflow dashboard or API, so that I can get these metrics?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`/questions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) method, which allows filtering by tag:

> To constrain questions returned to those with a set of tags, use the `tagged` parameter with a semi-colon delimited list of tags. This is an **and** constraint, passing `tagged=c;java` will return only those questions with both tags. As such, passing more than 5 tags will always return zero results.

The `view_count` is in the default [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), so you don't even need to adjust that. You might need to build some pagination logic, as the API will only return up to 100 results at a time (if you specify that as your `pagesize`).